# programme or program

Tags: nouns, orthography, doubled-consonants

I am wondering which is the correct version?

> 1. Furthermore, the official length of my **programme** of study: 3.5 years
>      of full-time study and 16 weeks of internship.
> 2. Furthermore, the official length of my **program** of study: 3.5 years of
>      full-time study and 16 weeks of internship.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's *programme* in the UK, except when it's a *computer program*.

Comment: Or quoting a US etc source. And never use the word when writing on a transatlantic flight.